# Postgres SQL: getting group count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
>> tbl_category

id | category
-------------
0  | A
1  | B
...|...

>>tbl_product

id | category_id | product
---------------------------
0  | 0           | P1 
1  | 1           | P2
...|...          | ...
```

I can use the following query to count the number of products in a category.

```
select category, count(tbl.product) from tbl_product 
join tbl_category on tbl_product.category_id = category.id 
group by catregory
```

However, there are some categories that never have any product belonging to. How do I get these to show up in the query result as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join`:

```
select c.category, count(tbl.product) 
from tbl_category c left join
     tbl_product p
     on p.category_id = c.id 
group by c.category;
```

The table where you want to keep all the rows goes first (`tbl_category`).

Note the use of table aliases to make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: You might add extra coalesce at count(tbl.product) to show 0 at least `coalesce(count(tbl.product),0)`.

Comment: @Lemur . . . Utterly unnecessary.  `COUNT()` returns `0`, not `NULL` if there are no matches.